# Create a text representation of an ActiveRecord object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Suppose we have some arbitrary Active Record object

```rb
obj = User.first
```

Is there a way to convert this into a *text representation*?

That is, is there a way to convert the object into some code that can be dropped into a completely different rails console to regenerate that same object?

The closest example I can give of this functionality is the [`dput()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/dput) function from the R programming language. Is there an equivalent in ruby / rails, preferably one that works with Active Record objects?

Answer (score 1):

Ruby has the [Marshal module](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Marshal.html):

> The marshaling library converts collections of Ruby objects into a
> byte stream, allowing them to be stored outside the currently active
> script. This data may subsequently be read and the original objects
> reconstituted.

```
str = Marshal.dump(obj)
# => "\x04\bo:\nThing\x1A:\x10@new_recordF:\x10@attributeso:\x1EActiveModel::AttributeSet\x06;\a{\tI\"\aid\x06:\x06ETo:)ActiveModel::Attribute::FromDatabase\n:\n@name@\b:\x1C@value_before_type_casti\x06:\n@typeo:EActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SQLite3Adapter::SQLite3Integer\t:\x0F@precision0:
```

You can then load the object back into memory:

```
restored_obj = Marshal.load(
  StringIO.new(str) # usually this would be from a IO stream like a file
)
```

It has some pretty serious security implications though if you're accepting user input and other serialization formats like JSON or Yaml should be considered. Three are also issues if you use it for caching and then change Ruby versions.

Rails models in recent versions also support Global ID - which doesn't give you the exact same object but it gives you a URI which can be used to load the same record from the database.

```
gid = User.first.to_global_id
obj = GlobalID::Locator.locate(gid)
```

This is how ActiveJob passes around references to models.